# How to release GIL in subprocess.Popen.communicate()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 `threading.Thread`s, and each calls:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(...)
o,e = p.communicate()
```

It seems that the `GIL` is not released when calling `p.communicate()`. In the above code, the threads become pipelined, only when the first thread finishes, the second can start and that's not the desired behavior.

Is there a way to wait on `Popen` in a way that releases the `GIL`?

Comment: Very interesting question. I'm going to chant *"Martijn Pieters, Martijn Pieters, Martijn Pieters!"* and hope that a diamond-studded answer appears below.

Comment: Do you pass any special parameters to Popen?  I use Popen in the same way as you but I set stdin/stdout/stderr to PIPE.

Comment: @rrrzx I do the same, but I doubt this has anything to do with the problem

Comment: @msw the communicate should and does block per thread, when you have mulitple threads each calling communicate I expect the GIL to be released so that both end up calling communicate concurrently.

Comment: @msw also communicate does not take a timeout option in python 2.7

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to put inside `Popen()`.  The answer will depend heavily on exactly what the subprogram is.

Comment: @SciProg I call different binaries that return to me text through stdout and errors through stderr.

Comment: You could have a look at https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/index.html. I don't know if it relates to your problem, but it is a module used to control applications from python. In the documentation, there is a mention of problems encountered with threads. Unfortunately, I only know this program by name (didn't use it much), so I cannot be of much help with it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use `multiprocessing` module instead of `threading`.

Look at the first sentence in the introduction of https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html.

Or, if you still want to use threads, do not call `communicate()`, but use stdin and stdout pipes.  You still have to be careful, because you may inadvertly lock a process that way.  This happens, for example, if you try to read from the process's `stdout` when there is no data available.  You have to know exactly when data is available, and how many bytes of it are available (this is not exactly polling).

```
p = subprocess.Popen( ..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
p.stdin.write( ... )
n = 1
x = p.stdout.read(n)  # this will lock if less than N bytes are available
```

Comment: I do not know the number of bytes to read unfortunately. And multiprocessing is precisely what I'm avoiding to use

Comment: There are other ways of doing it without knowing the number of bytes.  For example, you can read one byte at a time and stop when you encounter a terminating character (a new line or carriage return character).  It all depends on the subprogram being called by Popen.  Finally, I do not know if calling `p.stdout.read()` will block if used in threads.  I suggest you try it.

Comment: @msw because of a technical reason that would need an entire different thread to explain. Why does this keep coming up, my question is regarding threading library. If what I am asking isn't doable, that should be the answer.

Comment: @SciProg the method you described doesn't work somehow the GIL blocks and I can't figure out where for the life of me but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: I do really appreciate your answer and that you are trying to help, I really do. However I truly don't think you are understanding my question nor my comments. I understand that communicate will block, my question is that is there a way to achieve a similar behavior to communicate while at the same time having 2 threads progressing on reading on their corresponding popened scripts

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something else is going on. The blocking behavior you describe is not what I see with the following scripts:

start.py

```
import threading
import subprocess
import time


def run_script():
    print "Thread started"
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['./script.sh'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    print "Communicating"
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print out, err


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run_script)
thread1.start()

time.sleep(1)

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=run_script)
thread2.start()
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
   sleep 0.5
done
```

output

```
> python start.py
Thread started
Communicating
Thread started
Communicating
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times

Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
```

The second thread successfully starts and communicates after the first thread is already communicating with its process.